# std::get<I>( std::tuple& ) as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a `std::tuple` of objects. I can use `std::get<I>(std::tuple&)` to get the type of the object and hence automatically create them.

However, when I try to use that type as an argument to another template, I get errors. Behold...

```
class SpecificMessageHandler; // is valid.

template< class MessageT, class HandlerT >
class MessageCallbackHandler : public MessageCallbackInterface
{
  // ... yadda ...
}


template< class T >
class MessageFactory 
{
  // ... yadda ...

  template< std::size_t I = 0, typename ... T >
  inline typename std::enable_if< I < sizeof ... (T), void >::type
  initMsgMap( const std::tuple< T... >& t )
  {
    const auto& msg( std::get<I>( t ) ); // works fine
    m_messageMap[ msg.getMessageID() ] = msg.clone(); // works fine

    new MessageCallbackHandler
      < std::get<I>( t ), SpecificMessageHandler >(); // error, complains about arg 1

    initMsgMap< I + 1, T... >( t );
  }

  // This is the base case, upon which we do nothing.
  //
  template< std::size_t I = 0, typename ... T >
  inline typename std::enable_if< I == sizeof... (T), void >::type
  initMsgMap( const std::tuple< T... >& ) { }
}
```

Sayeth gcc ...

```
MessageFactory.H: In member function 'typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof (T ...)),
void>::type AWHF::MessageFactory<MessageTuple>::initMsgMap(const std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&)':
awhf/MessageFactory.H:266:54: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template
parameter list for 'template<class MessageT, class HandlerT> class
AWHF::MessageCallbackHandler' < std::get<I>( t ), SpecificMessageHandler >() ;
```

Comment: As the error message is saying, get returns a value, and the template wants a type.

Comment: That was what I figured; I didn't know of the existence of `std::tuple_element<>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want `std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<T...>>::type`
`std::get` doesn't return a *type*.

Comment: `typename std::tuple_element<...>::type` is what technically "returns" the type.